# kill several processes using awk tools

Tags: awk, grep, kill

I want to stop several processes using awk.My command is like this:

```
sudo ps -ef|grep wget |grep -v grep|awk '{print $2;sudo kill -STOP $2}'
```

I want to stop all processes which is running wget. $2 of awk means the pid of each process.But I find that it doesn't work.The state of process remains the same.They are still running.

Instead , I modified this command:

```
sudo ps -ef|grep wget |grep -v grep|awk '{print $2}'|xargs sudo kill -STOP
```

it works! So , anyone can tell me the difference of them ?

Comment: Do you really want to kill processes of other users?

Answer (score 8):

There is a lot to be improved about your approach:

1. On most systems (if `/proc` is not mounted with `hidepid`) you don't need `root` privilege for `ps`.
2. There is no need for two `grep` instances just to get rid of the first in the process list. Do this instead: `grep '[w]get'`
3. There is no use in `grep` filtering input for `awk`. `awk` can do that pretty well on its own: `awk '/wget/ {print $2}'` (or, due to the `ps` problem: `awk '/[w]get/ {print $2}'`)
4. Instead of filtering `ps` output and piping PIDs to `kill` you could just use `killall wget`
5. You would call `sudo` once for `awk` and not once per input line.

The main problem in your first pipeline is the `awk` command: `awk '{print $2;sudo kill -STOP $2}'`. You can run external commands from `awk` but not this way. You need this `awk` function: `system(cmd-line)`

If you want to use `ps` and `kill` then do it this way:

```
kill -STOP $(ps -ef | awk '/[w]get/ {print $2}')
```

Answer (score 3):

I know your question is about the difference in both the commands you had tried, but if you are not insistent about using `awk`, and for the benefit of anyone else who may stumble upon this post, another method would be to use `pgrep -f`.

`kill $(pgrep -f wget)`

This will kill all the process that is using `wget`. Use the signal that you wish to use with `kill` (if any).

Answer (score 1):

For improvement, see [@Hauke Laging's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/173859/38906).

For the difference between yours solution, the first approach does not run `kill` command, it just refer to four variables `sudo`, `kill`, `STOP` and `$2`.

At least in `gawk`, when you refer to variables with no action in a statement, it do nothing. You can easily use `dgawk` to see that:

```
$ dgawk -f test.awk
dgawk> trace on
dgawk> run
Starting program: 
[     1:0x7f8d697fffe0] Op_rule             : [in_rule = BEGIN] [source_file = test.awk]
[     2:0x7f8d697fef60] Op_push_i           : 2 [PERM|NUMCUR|NUMBER]
[     2:0x7f8d697fef40] Op_field_spec       : 
[     2:0x7f8d697fef20] Op_K_print          : [expr_count = 1] [redir_type = ""]

[     2:0x7f8d697fefa0] Op_push             : sudo
[     2:0x7f8d697fefc0] Op_push             : kill
[     2:0x7f8d697ff040] Op_push             : STOP
[     2:0x7f8d697ff000] Op_minus            : 
[      :0x7f8d697ff080] Op_no_op            : 
[     2:0x7f8d697ff020] Op_push_i           : 2 [PERM|NUMCUR|NUMBER]
[     2:0x7f8d697ff060] Op_field_spec       : 
[      :0x7f8d697ff0c0] Op_concat           : [expr_count = 3] [concat_flag = 0]
[      :0x7f8d697ff0a0] Op_pop              : 
[      :0x7f8d697fee80] Op_no_op            : 
[      :0x7f8d697fef00] Op_atexit           : 
[      :0x7f8d697fefe0] Op_stop             : 
Program exited normally with exit value: 0
```

Pay attention at `Op_no_op` byte-code.

For run external command from `awk`, you can use `awk` [system()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_14) function:

```
awk '{print $2;system("sudo kill -STOP " $2)}'
```